# C++ Server doesn't work after being put in a container

Tags: c++, docker, tcp

When running my server and client normally, no issues present themselves, so I don't think the issue has to do with the client/server itself, but I'll post it anyways.

RTCServer.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h> 

#include "Room.h"

using namespace std;

//TODO: figure out ptr situation
void* handleConnection(void* p_room) {
    Room* room = (Room *)p_room;
    int clientSocket = room->getNewest();
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];      // Client's remote name
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];   // port the client is connect on  
    memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST); 
    memset(service, 0, NI_MAXSERV);
       
    // accept and echo message back to client
    char buf[4096];
    while (true) {
        memset(buf, 0, 4096);
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
        std::cout << "from client at " << clientSocket << "\n";
        if (bytesReceived == -1) {
            cerr << "Error in recv(). Quitting" << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (bytesReceived == 0) {
            cout << "Client disconnected " << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;

        // Echo message back to all clients
        std::vector<int> members = room->members();
        for (int i = 0; i < room->size(); i++) {
            send(members[i], buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);
        }  
    }
    //?
    close(clientSocket);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Create a socket
    int serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocket == -1) {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind the ip address and port to a socket
    sockaddr_in sockInfo;
    sockInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockInfo.sin_port = htons(54000);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &sockInfo.sin_addr);
    bind(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&sockInfo, sizeof(sockInfo));
    listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    
    // Wait for a connection
    // Create new thread and handle
    Room room;
    while(1) {
        sockaddr_in client;
        socklen_t clientSize = sizeof(client);
        int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
        std::cout << clientSocket << "\n";
        room.addMember(clientSocket);
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handleConnection, &room);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

RTCClient.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h> 

using namespace std;

void* toServer(void* info) {
    pair<string, int>* pairPtr = (pair<string,int>*)info;
    string username = pairPtr->first;
    int sock = pairPtr->second; 
    char buf[4096];
    string userInput;
    while(1) {
        cout << "> ";
        getline(cin, userInput);
        //Send to server
        string msg = username + " :: " + userInput; 
        int sendRes = send(sock, msg.c_str(), msg.size() + 1, 0);
        if (sendRes == -1) {
            cout << "Could not send to server!\n";
            continue;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* fromServer(void* info) {    
    int sock = *(int *)info;
    char buf[4096];
    while(1) {
        memset(buf, 0, 4096);
        std::cout << "about to recv" << "\n";
        int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (bytesReceived == -1) {
            cout << "There was an error getting a response from server\n";
        }
        //Display response
        else {
            cout << string(buf, bytesReceived) << "\n";
        }
    }  
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "use format ./client <username>\n";
        return 1;
    }
    string username = argv[1];
    //Create a socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        return 1;
    }

    //Create a hint structure for the server we're connecting with
    int port = 54000;
    string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    //Connect to the server on the socket
    int connectRes = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    std::cout << "connected" << "\n";
    if (connectRes == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    pair<string, int> pairPtr = {username, sock};
    pthread_t toServerThread;
    pthread_create(&toServerThread, NULL, toServer, &pairPtr);
    

    
    pthread_t fromServerThread;
    pthread_create(&fromServerThread, NULL, fromServer, &sock);
    

    while (1) {}

    //Close the socket
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile both with `g++ *.cpp -lpthread -o <name>`
My Dockerfile so far is simple and I just want to get the server running in a container before I move on.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY server /
ENTRYPOINT ["./server"]
```

I then build the image with:

```
docker build -t chatserver .
```

To run the image I do:

```
docker run -d -p 54000:80 --name chatserver chatserver
```

Once I execute the client, no actual connection is made and the functionality of the project is gone. I suspect my issue has to do with the way the ports of the client and server are exposed.

Comment: Why do I see port 80 in the docker command line?

Comment: The server also needs to bind to the special "all interfaces" address 0.0.0.0.  If it binds to 127.0.0.1 as you show, it won't be reachable from outside its own container.

Comment: Thank you this was also my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mapping the port in the docker container to 80 - so either change your server code to bind to port 80 or use `docker ... -p 54000:54000 ...`

Answer (score 0):

practical tip:
on your devcontainer.json
add

```
"appPort":["54000:54000/tcp"],
```

(use udp otherwise, i'm using VSCode)